# continue seasonality of time series from forecast stl decomposition

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

The `stl` function in the `stats` package decomposes a time series into seasonal, trend, and remainder:

```
sstl <- stl(ts(rnorm(100), frequency=12), "period")
plot(sstl)
```

[image]

The seasonality is a regular pattern, how can I continue this pattern for the next 50 data points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the unique values of the seasonal component and then use `rep_len` to create a vector of length 150 as follows

```
rep_len(unique(sstl$time.series[, "seasonal"]), length.out = 150)
```

[image]